# How do I initialize a matchTemplateBuff in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm writing a pattern matching code using OpenCV with CUDA on Mac OS X. After ~ 70 frames, it slows down a lot. Using mach_absolute_time() I've been able to track the culprit (Initially I thought it was a disk access issue):

```
gpu::matchTemplate(currentFrame,
                   correlationTargets[i]->correlationImage,
                   temporaryImage,
                   CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
```

I believe this is caused by some memory issue inside matchTemplate. After a lot of search, I found the matchTemplateBuf structure which is presumably for memory reuse. Since the problem seems memory releated, I think using this may be the solution. However, the following code crashes:

```
gpu::MatchTemplateBuf mtBuff;

[...]

for(...) {

gpu::matchTemplate(correlationTargets[i]->croppedImage,
                   correlationTargets[i]->correlationImage,
                   correlationTargets[i]->maxAllocation,
                   CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED, mtBuff);
```

With error:

```
OpenCV Error: Gpu API call (Unknown error code [Code = 9999]) in convolve,     file /Users/sermarc/Downloads/opencv-2.4-3.8/modules/gpu/src/imgproc.cpp, line 1431 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Users/sermarc/Downloads/opencv-2.4-3.8/modules/gpu/src/imgproc.cpp:1431: error: (-217) Unknown error code [Code = 9999] in function convolve
```

I believe this is because the matchTemplateBuff is not properly initialized. However, I cannot find any information or example that shows it being set on a valid state.

The code works with:

```
gpu::matchTemplate(correlationTargets[i]->croppedImage,
                   correlationTargets[i]->correlationImage,
                   correlationTargets[i]->maxAllocation,
                   CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
```